# VBA: Can't get "xlPastevaluesAndNumberFormats" to work

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have been trying to copy a range from an excel and paste it to the embedded excel of a native chart in PPT using **xlPastevaluesAndNumberFormats** of *PasteSpecial* method. For some reason it is not working. Could somebody help me understand what I am getting wrong.

Sample code and error pic below:

```
 Private Sub UpdateSlide(targetslide As PowerPoint.Slide, thatsheet As Worksheet)

 Dim StoreArray As Variant
 Dim aShp As PowerPoint.Shape
 Dim rng As Range
 Set rng = thatsheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
 rng.Copy
' StoreArray = rng   
 
 For Each aShp In targetslide.Shapes
      If aShp.HasChart Then
        With aShp.Chart.ChartData
               Dim del_rng As Range
               Set del_rng = .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") '.CurrentRegion
               'del_rng.Resize(UBound(StoreArray, 1), UBound(StoreArray, 2)) = StoreArray  'This option works but screws up formatting
               del_rng.PasteSpecial (xlPastevaluesAndNumberFormats) 'Fails here
```

[image]

Comment: I have answered a similar question before. Let me find the link. one moment

Comment: You are setting your range as `aShp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")`?

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872887/why-does-pastespecial-method-sometimes-throw-error-1004) it is. Put the line `rng.Copy` just before `del_rng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats)`. Also insert `Doevents` between those 2 lines.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Okay, Thanks lemme quickly try that out. But as mentioned the xlpasteall works fine for some reason, Any insights as to why ?

Comment: @DarrellH yes, the idea is to get data to the embedded excel of a chart.

Comment: Works fine for me in sample data. nothing wrong with the line `del_rng .PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats)` :) Try what I mentioned above ans see if you are still getting the error?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi, I tried it and now it is giving me the linked file not available error i.e the embedded excel can't be opened. Will restart and see. This ppt automation is a nightmare compared to excel though... :D

Comment: That is a different error. Your paste error is gone it seems :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am afraid not, moving the line inside as you suggested causes a new run time error 462

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234167/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-charlie).

Answer (score 1):

Further to what I have mentioned in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872887/why-does-pastespecial-method-sometimes-throw-error-1004) post, you need to activate the backend Excel workbook before you can paste to native powerpoint chart (Insert | Chart) workbook else you will get the error as shown below.

[image]

To activate the backend excel book, use

```
aShp.Chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow
```

Combining both suggestions, your code can be written as

```
Private Sub UpdateSlide(targetslide As PowerPoint.Slide, thatsheet As Worksheet)
    Dim StoreArray As Variant
    Dim aShp As PowerPoint.Shape
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim chartsheet As Worksheet
    Dim del_rng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = thatsheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    For Each aShp In targetslide.Shapes
        If aShp.HasChart Then
            With aShp.Chart.ChartData
                Set wb = .Workbook
                Set chartsheet = wb.Sheets(1)
                Set del_rng = chartsheet.Range("A1")
                
                aShp.Chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow

                rng.Copy
                DoEvents
                del_rng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

                row_1 = .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A100").End(xlUp).Row
                col_1 = .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("AZ1").End(xlToLeft).Column
                
                Set chartsheet = Nothing
                Set del_rng = Nothing
                
                wb.Close (True)

                Set wb = Nothing
            End With

            With aShp
                .Chart.SetSourceData _
                Source:="='Sheet1'!$A$1:" & .Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(row_1, col_1).Address
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so  much, Siddharth. It is working...... :)

Comment: Anyone following this, please note that aShp.Chart.ChartData.Activate does't work. Why it doesn't work is beyond me. Let's hope some expert *cough *cough *siddharth *cough may help us out here ..... :D

Comment: It does work. What error are you getting? BTW why are you using that and to achieve what purpose?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get ya. I said  aShp.Chart.ChartData.Activate doesn't work but aShp.Chart.ChartData.ActivateChartDataWindow works. I was asking if anybody can shed a light on as to why ?

Comment: For me both lines do not give any error :) For your case however we need `ActivateChartDataWindow`

Comment: Excel gods have probably blessed you.

Comment: Yeah...unfortunately it isn't working on loops. Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. Unaccepted just so if anybody has any other idea, they won't go without chiming in

Comment: "It isn't working" is not a very helpful statement. You need to share more details. Also what happens if you add this one line `Doevents` after `If aShp.HasChart Then`

Comment: Well It works well for individual charts, but as soon as put it to work in a loop, it starts behaving abnormally. In some cases it took all the time to execute and yet nothing was updated.

Comment: Did you use DoEvents?

Comment: Yes, i did.  This seems like one of those vba quirks.

Comment: Can yuo update the question with the final code that you are using?

Comment: It is the same code that you have suggested with the latest update of inserting Do Events after ashp.haschart line. As I said works fine for individual cases, but in a loop it behaves unpredictably. So I decided to avoid paste special altogether.