# selection.Pastespecial not working in excel. Get Run-time error 1004. How do I solve this

Tags: excel, vba

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="RecordCount", RefersToR1C1:="=tblConveyanceLevelTCArrivedVsRe!R1C100"

Range("CV1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(C[-99])"

RecordCount = Range("RecordCount")

Range("A2:L" & RecordCount).Select

'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.Copy

Windows("TC Receiving Report Template.xlsm").Activate
      
Sheets("Arrived Vs Received Status").Select

Range("A2").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
    
Windows("ConveyanceLevelTCArrivedVsReceivedStatus.xlsx").Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I am not sure why the paste.special feature is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872887/why-does-pastespecial-method-sometimes-throw-error-1004